# Different Site Collection Templates

Tags: site-collection, publishing-site, team-sites, communication-site

my company wants to make a site where they can share some documents with their clients from different countries. Each country should have their own home page with different pictures (should we use different sites or can we use different permissions on 1 page to achieve this based on user's groups?).

They also want to apply branding to the pages using custom layouts, which is not possible in Communication site if I'm not mistaken.

Which site collection templates should we used?Publishing, team site or other template?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Each country should have their own home page with different pictures you can

1) create html markups(branding) and insert the list view web part into the html markup(for documents have different List/library targeting group of users).

2)Create a page where you want to display the information.

3) Add content editor webpart for different countries and reference the html prepared (branding) according the country and set the target audience by creating groups.

Answer (score 0):

I would preferred to use Publishing team site, it will help us to maintain the page layout, versioning and collaboration features for the Pages and documents.
I will also help you to leverage some enterprise features like document/content sharing, look and feel (master page) inheritance and manage Navigation structure through out the application